How to Add Custom Plugin on TinyMce on Magento 2.4.6
As you know, in the new version of the menu and number of plugins have not been installed. How can I install them again so that I can make the editor more complete?
Magento 2.4.5 old version :

Magento 2.4.6 Version :

Please Help !
